# How are WPA2 passwords encoded?

Tags: wifi, wpa2, encoding, wpa2-psk

I'm trying to figure out a good John The Ripper rule for WPA2 that won't waste time testing impossible passwords. Thus the question - are there any limits on what's allowed in a WPA2 password? Can it be any binary string or are we limited to ASCII or a particular encoding? Is its length any limited? I remember that there's a minimum password length limit.

Answer (score 4):

According to the 802.11i-2004 specification ([link to download 802.11i-2004 pdf](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11i-2004.pdf)):

> A pass-phrase is a sequence of between 8 and 63 ASCII-encoded characters. The limit of 63 comes from the desire to distinguish between a pass-phrase and a PSK displayed as 64 hexadecimal characters.

Comment: Thanks. This means that I can throw away all diacritic symbols?

Comment: That is correct! @d33tah